# How do I search a Pandas dataframe for each element in a series or liist?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Starting with a list or a series, I want to search every column in a DataFrame (or select columns) for each instance of each item in that list/series.

Here is an example:

```
color_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'list1' : ['blue','green','red','yellow'],
    'list2' : ['red', 'orange', 'purple', 'brown'],
    'list3' : ['black', 'white', 'purple', 'pink']
})
```

I'd like to search that DF for each color and then document each column that contains that column. I have some code that works, but I suspect there is a way to do it in a vectorized manner (using an apply function and isin perhaps?).

Here is what I am doing now:

1. create a deduped list of all the colors-

```
all_entries = []
for col in color_df:
    col_colors = color_df[col].to_list()
    all_entries = all_entries + col_colors
all_entries = list(set(all_entries))
```

3. search each col for each item in that list and create a new DF where the index is the colors and there is a 1/0 for each column that contains that color.

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame()
for x in all_entries:
    for col in color_df:
        if x in color_df[col].to_list():
            result_df.loc[x, col] = 1
        else:
            result_df.loc[x, col] = 0
result_df['counts'] = result_df.apply(sum, axis=1)
result_df = result_df.sort_values(by='counts', ascending=False)
```

The result_df gives me what I want, but I feel confident there is a more elegant way to do this. Apologies if a similar question has been asked, I am not sure if my search terms were great when I looked initially. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a tip, you can use ```set(color_df.values.flatten())``` to get all unique values in data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use unstack() and crosstab() for this:

```
color_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'list1' : ['blue','green','red','yellow'],
    'list2' : ['red', 'orange', 'purple', 'brown'],
    'list3' : ['black', 'white', 'purple', 'pink']})
```

---

```
df = color_df.unstack().reset_index()
df = pd.crosstab(df[0], df["level_0"], dropna=False)
df["counts"] = df.apply(sum, axis=1)
```

---

```
Out[85]: 
level_0  list1  list2  list3  counts
0                                   
black        0      0      1       1
blue         1      0      0       1
brown        0      1      0       1
green        1      0      0       1
orange       0      1      0       1
pink         0      0      1       1
purple       0      1      1       2
red          1      1      0       2
white        0      0      1       1
yellow       1      0      0       1
```

Comment: Thank you Andreas! I have not worked with the crosstab function before.

Comment: @Etanial I am glad I could help. Happy coding!